# Reformatting the data frame by removing unwanted headers and reindexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
"Some Merged Cell
 is appearing "          Unnamed:1                   Unnamed:2      Unnamed:3 
 Sl.No            Description of Work / Item(s)      Item Code      No.of Qty
  1                   2                               3             4
  1          Total for item no. 1 for yard 3025  Item 1 Yard 3025   1
  2          Total for item no. 2 for yard 3025  Item 2 Yard 3025   1
  3          Total for item no. 3 for yard 3025  Item 3 Yard 3025   1
Total in Figures            
Quoted Rate in Figures          
Quoted Rate in Words
```

I want to have a clean dataframe like below

```
Sr. No     Description of Work          ItemCode           No.of Qty
 1         Total for Item 1 Yard 3025  Item 1 Yard 3025      1
 2         Total for Item 2 Yard 3025  Item 1 Yard 3025      1
```

And so on.

Is there any clue on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

first change the columns names, using:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0] #set the first row as the header
df = df[1:] #remove the first row
```

next, to change the index, use [pandas.setIndex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('S1.No')
```